# Get substring after first letter in string MS Access SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

in MS Access I have a column "Test":

| Test |
| --- |
| 1.1.8.5.200.484.56.1.27.85.266.6.3.332.1 Entry Test Blabla |
| 7.55.41.6.4.77.4541.58.5654.123.2.2.123 Another entry I need to extract |
| Test Test New Entry |

I want to display a new column, where everything before the first **letter** is removed, like:

| FilteredColumn |
| --- |
| Entry Test Blabla |
| Another entry I need to extract |
| Test Test New Entry |

I tried using the mid() and InStr() function as followed:

```sql
Select

mid([Test], InStr([Test], '[az-AZ]')) as FilteredColumn

From TableA;
```

this should've returned the first occurence of a letter via the InStr() function and use that position as starting point for the mid() function.

This doesn't work unfortunately. I tried it with left() instead of mid() as well, but no success.

Comment: First character or first "space" character? Did you try changing `"[a-z]"` to `" "`

Comment: Rather first character (letter) instead of space, to be safe in case anything changes in the future.

Comment: I still tried it with only `' '` (Space), but this resolved in the same error "invalid procedure call", although I got the syntax of the functions from Microsofts documentation itself:
[Mid](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mid-function-427e6895-822c-44ee-b34a-564a28f2532c)

[InStr](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/instr-function-85d3392c-3b1c-4232-bb18-77cd0cb8a55b)

[Wildcard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-wildcard-characters-939e153f-bd30-47e4-a763-61897c87b3f4)

Comment: `InStr` returns 0 when the string is not found and `Mid(..., 0, ...)` will throw up. Also, I don't think wildcards work inside `InStr` function. One solution (which I did not verify myself) is to use `IIF` to check if string contains at least one space using `InStr`... if it returns > 0 then go with `Mid` otherwise return the string as-is.

Comment: Well then I'll go with your first approach by doing it with the space character. This one works now, there was something wrong with the query before, when it threw the error message. Thank you Salman! If you post that as answer, I'll mark it as solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't describe the error but I am guessing you were getting `Invalid procedure call or argument` error. What happens is this:

- The `InStr` function can search for a string, not a pattern

  - So it returns 0 when it cannot find the *string* `[az-AZ]`
- The `Mid` function expects a number greater than 0 and thus throws an error

The workaround is to look for space character in the string, if it is present then extract the portion after it:

```sql
SELECT IIf(InStr(Test, ' ') > 0, Mid(Test, InStr(Test, ' ') + 1), Test)
FROM ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that is one working solution!
But does this also take in account rows, that already start with letters and shouldn't be trimmed by the IIF statement?

For example if I have a row that contains the data "New Entry Test blabla", will this result in "Entry Test blabla" and thus I loose information I wanted to keep?

Comment: That changes things. You can use `LIKE` for the test condition... `Test LIKE '[0-9]% %'` to check if string starts with a digit and contains a space (access wildcards are different so you need to change it).